# codename one where put sd card files in debug progress

Tags: codenameone, system-paths, file-system-storage

I am trying to read a file located in my phone with the `FileSystemStorage` class:

```
is = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(updateFilePath);
```

But i don't know where to put this `updateFilePath` in my local machine for development, so for testing this part i have been forced to test it (as a blackbox) with an app built for android. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

For testing you can add the file in the following folder
%userprofile%\.cn1 in Windows